# how to make javascript variable global and pass it into function ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have live file reading 
and i'm getting the files name from many links

```
name_container="<div><a class=\"friendclick\" data-frclick=\"$fr\" href=\"#\">$fullname</a></div>";
```

i need when (data-frclick) change -it changes on click- i need to pass it's value  (targetread=dat) as (dat)

```
$('.friendclick').click(function(){
var dat=$(this).data('frclick');
});
```

i tried to put comet() function inside the click event function , it worked only when i click the link ,

but i couldn't get any live update from the file automatically, maybe if you can help me with making the (dat) global variable ,or any other suggestions !

```
$('.friendclick').click(function(){
 dat=$(this).data('frclick');

var timestamp = null;  //read
function comet() {

$.ajax({
    type : 'Get',
    url  : 'includes/read.php?timestamp=' + timestamp+'&targetread='+dat,
    async : true,
    cache : false,

    success : function(data) {
                var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
                if(json['msg'] == ''){
                    $('#msg').html('No msg');                   
                }else { 
                    $('#msg').html(json['msg']);
                         $('#msg').animate({scrollTop:$('#msg').get(0).scrollHeight},200);

                }
                timestamp  = json['timestamp'];
                setTimeout('comet()', 1000);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, error) { 
                //alert(error);
                setTimeout('comet()', 65000);
    }       
});
 }

 $(function() { // write
comet();
$('#send').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var msg = $(this).val();
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {  
        return ; 
    }else if(msg!='' && e.keyCode == 13) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url  : 'includes/write.php?msg='+ msg.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')+'&target='+dat,
            async : true,
            cache : false
        });
        $(this).val('')
    }
});
 });

 });
```

and the php page for reading the file 
     $target=$_GET['targetread'];
here i got the target file 
then from the DB i get $file_name

```
    $filename = 'messaging/'.$file_name.'.txt';
$last = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$current = filemtime($filename);

while( $current <= $last) {
    usleep(100000);
    clearstatcache();
    $current = filemtime($filename);
}

$response = array();
$response['msg'] = file_get_contents($filename);
$response['timestamp'] = $current;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: `var json = eval('(' + data + ')');` ***sigh*** Once you've eval'd it, it's not JSON anymore. JSON is a *textual* notation for data interchange. The result of parsing it is an object graph. (And using `eval` to parse JSON is a Bad Idea. Use `JSON.parse`, that's what it's for.)

Comment: 2. Passing strings into `setTimeout` is an anti-pattern. Use `setTimeout(comet, 1000);` instead.

Comment: What's the question? What behavior are you expecting, what do you see instead...?

Comment: guys the code is working fine but i need to make the variable (dat) global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Caution

I'll preface this answer with the statement that globals can be the cause of major headaches and confusion.  Use them with care, if at all.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) as to why.

### Quick and Dirty

One (very hack-ish) option is to set a property of the `window` object.

Something like:

```
$('.friendclick').click(function(){
    var dat=$(this).data('frclick');
    window.myglobalvariable = dat;
});
```

Then you can reference it anywhere as `window.myglobalvariable`.

This probably isn't a very good solution, but without seeing how your code works at a higher level and understanding the scope of your ajax call and your click event, it's hard to make a better recommendation.

This will have the same effect as defining a variable without `var`:

```
$('.friendclick').click(function(){
    var dat=$(this).data('frclick');
    myglobalvariable = dat;
});
```

It's just a bit more clear as to what's happening.

### Refactor

The other option is to re-factor your code such that you don't have to use a global variable.  Depending on how your click event and `comet()` function are scoped, you might be able to do something like this:

```
$('.friendclick').click(function(){
    var mydata = $(this).data('frclick');
    comet(mydata);
});

function comet(data)
{
   ... code that makes ajax call with "data" as an argument ...
}
```

Comment: sadly didn't work , ok ,i'm gonna edit the question and i'll put the whole code

Comment: The `window` object is global by nature.  Setting a property there will make your data global.  If it "didn't work", please check your browser console, add some `alert()` and `console.log()` calls at various points in your code to make sure your data is moving along where it needs to.

Comment: i tried  it
        

Uncaught ReferenceError: myglobalvariable is not defined

Comment: thank you , it was passing the comet() the variable dat